# find max match count set from multiple set

Tags: java, algorithm, count

I am looking for best solution to find matching set with max string match.
Here is example,

```
inSet = ["a","b","c","x"]
```

other list of set

```
set1 = ["a","d","q","s"]
set2 = ["a","m","t","b","z"]
set3 = ["a","x","b","s","r","t"]
```

in above example, set3 is max. match count (3).

what is best algorithm to find with minimal execution.
any pointer or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: What is your initial idea? And why would(n't) it be as optimal as you think? Please show us your solution to this problem!

Comment: For start, you can use new Set<>(inSet).retainAll(set1/set2/set3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us have `Set<String> set` and *Guava.Sets*:

```
Set<Set<String>> set = new Set<>();
//add Set<String>s
Set<String> maxMatchSet = set.stream()
                              .max(Comparator.comparingInt((value -> Sets.intersection(value, inSet).size()))
                              .get();
```

OK, now some theory. `["a", "b"]` isn't a set but an array (or a list). We have different data structures in Java. Sets are represented in `{}`.

Anyway, what matters is the code.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

would initialize the `Set` and

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

would initialize the `List`. Still there is another option:

```
String[] array = new String[3];
```

would initialize new array of size 3. Arrays are fixed length.

Comment: In my question, my intension was to provide data set, didn't looked at  representation. Thanks for your suggestion, I will be careful going forward.

Comment: @Bharat happy to hear it - most of the times, people don't know Guava...